# What's wrong with this HQL? Getting No data type for node

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I wrote the following HQL:

```
select currency, rate from Currency as currency left outer join ExchangeRate as rate where currency.code = rate.currencyCode
```

And when I execute it I get: `No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode \r\n \\-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'rate' {originalText=rate}\r\n`

I found some questions on stackoverflow such as [What's wrong with this HQL? "No data type for node"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012408/whats-wrong-with-this-hql-no-data-type-for-node) but in my case rate is defined in my join. 
And suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure code is the foriegn key? Can you please send the table constraints and also the entity classes?

Comment: Yes, code is the FK. And I don't have access to the code right now, but the fields are non null, one currency > many rates. And they are both present in my persistence.xml